# Recurrence relation paths traced on a tetrahedron

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, recurrence-relations, recursion

I am attempting a recurrence relation question in which the number of possible length $n$ paths $a_n$ is being calculated. A path is defined as a traversal along a tetrahedron between connected vertices. All valid paths must return to the original vertex at the end of the path. The example given labels the vertices $ABCD$ and shows that the value of $a_2$ is $3$ - $ABA$, $ACA$ and $ADA$ are the only valid paths.

The question is what is the formula that defines this recurrence relation? The answer stated is $a_n=2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$ but I don't understand where the $2a_{n-1}$ comes from. The $3a_{n-2}$ term makes sense as one could traverse any length two path - $3$ of them - and then do a path of length $n-2$ and this would be a valid path of length $n$.

Comment: You're looking for an intuitive interpretation of the terms of the recurrence, which is, of course, the best way to understand what's going on here. I'll point out the number of paths of length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ of any graph is given by the $(i,j)$-th element of $A^n$, where $A$ is the graph's adjacency matrix. (The adjacency matrix itself obviously gives the length-$1$ paths; conveniently, the way matrix products *work* gives the appropriate recursion.) The adjacency matrix of the tetrahedron is simple; deriving a recurrence from its powers is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $2 a_{n-1}$ term can be described by taking any path, which must start with $AX$ where $X \in \{B,C,D\}$. Now, which ever one $X$ is, there are two others $Y$ and $Z$, for example if $X=B$ then $Y=C$ and $Y=D$. So you can replace $AX$ with either $AYX$ or $AZX$, which gives $2 a_{n-1}$ new paths.

But there's still an issue. The reason why this method counts every length $n$ path exactly once is:

- If a path starts $AXA$ then it is counted in the $3 a_{n-2}$ term --- just remove the initial $AXA$;
- If it starts $AXY$ then it is counted in the $2 a_{n-1}$ term --- just replace the initial $AXY$ by $AY$.